# How to compile single java file with multiple top level classes

Tags: java, class

This is my java code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class student
{
    String name;
    int age;
    float cgpa;
}
public class getdata
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int n;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        n=in.nextInt();
        student[] s=new student[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            s[i]=new student();
            s[i].name=in.nextLine();
            s[i].age=in.nextInt();
            s[i].cgpa=in.nextFloat();
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Name\tAge\tCGPA\n");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(s[i].name+"\t"+s[i].age+"\t"+s[i].cgpa+"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile the program, it gives the error that each class should be in a different file. How can i compile this without any error? (I know this is not the best practice, but I need to do this in the same file.)

Comment: What is the file name you are using to compile it?

Comment: You can have only one public top level class in a java file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is that you can have **only one public class** in a Java file.

If you want it to be visible from everywhere (this is based on your comment)  you can declare the class as public static inside the getdata.

It will be something like this:

```
public class getdata {
   public static class user {
     //class definition here
  }
}
```

Now your User class is available for instantiation everywhere.

Comment: But we wouldn't be able to use the second class in the program if it is `private` or `protected`. Right?

Comment: It does not need to be private or protected. You can declare it as public static for example. This way it will be accessible from everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Make the class Student to an inner class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class getdata
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int n;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        n=in.nextInt();
        student[] s=new student[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            s[i]=new student();
            s[i].name=in.nextLine();
            s[i].age=in.nextInt();
            s[i].cgpa=in.nextFloat();
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Name\tAge\tCGPA\n");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(s[i].name+"\t"+s[i].age+"\t"+s[i].cgpa+"\n");
        }
    }
    public static class student
    {
        String name;
        int age;
        float cgpa;
    }

}
```

File name must be `getdata.java`. And read about java naming convention. Class names should start with uppercase letter.

Comment: and make it a [static nested](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) class (`public static class student`) or else it won't compile :)

Comment: Please stick to the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and start classes with an upper case letter. Why this can also be said for @AlexanderPetrov the OP  I'll commented it to your post as you have by far the highest reputation here on SO and therefore probably should have known better

Answer (score 1):

You can make an inner class as mentioned before, or if you don't need to access this class from outside this file then just remove the public tag.  This will allow you to put multiple top level classes in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `.class` file and then simply run class you want to compile

`javac FileName.java`

`java fileName_containsMainMethod`

**EDIT** class cannot be public

eg
Consider the following class is saved as name `Test.java` and contain Two classes under single Name Test.java

```
class A
{
public static void main(String[] a)
{
System.out.println("Hello from A");
}
}

class B
{
public static void main(String[] a)
{
System.out.println("Hello from B");
}
}
```

Now to run this you need to do following
`javac Test.java`

> To get Output from Class A

`java A`

> To get Output from Class B

`java B`

**NOTE** Remove public access modifier from `class`